# CoreData. How Do I Seed My Data Model from an XML File?

Tags: ios, xml, core-data, data-modeling

In general I am warming to CoreData but I am currently spinning my wheels on how to seed my data model which is a cyclical object graph from a XML file with is a plain ole a-cyclical data graph.

Specifically, I have this - contrived - cyclical pattern in my data model:

A.b ----------------> B
B.a ----------------> A

A.widgets ------->> Widget
Widget.a ---------> A

B.widgets ------------->> Widget
Widget.b --------------> B

My XML file is loosely related to the data model so I need to do some re-mapping/futzing to parse its data in the data model but that is not the heart of my problem. I am struggling with how to handle the cyclical nature of the data model graph. How do I knit the entities together properly, robustly? There is no "root" to the object graph so an obvious traversal is not clear.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have solved this for various xml and json loading needs but have not made a generalized solution.

1. Render this cyclical graph as a tree with a root.  Choose the root in a way that makes sense for your application.
2. Uniquely identify each node that will be referenced.
3. Refer to each node that is not below the current node(the cyclical parts that the tree broke) by using its identifier.  Add that "soft link" to the model as well.
4. Map identifiers to objects in a dictionary while loading and creating them.
5. After completely loading the initial tree, iterate through your model in the same fashion as your xml tree to resolve soft-links.  Load the objects they refer to from the dictionary and assign them in the model.

Comment: Thanks Peter. Looks promising. Cheers.